# Rails helper file for a namespaced controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller "ott_controller.rb" in the folder "api".

My routes look like this:

  `map.namespace :api, :path_prefix => 'api' do |api|
    api.connect 'ott/playlists/:id.xml', :controller => 'ott', :action => 'playlists', :conditions => { :method => :get }
  end`

I'm trying to create a helper file for this, but I can't get it to pick up.

In the helpers folder, I've tried the following

1. File "ott_helper.rb" with module "OttHelper"
2. File "api_ott_helper.rb" with module "OttHelper"
3. File "ott_helper.rb" with module "Api::OttHelper"
4. File "api_ott_helper.rb" with module "Api::OttHelper"

None of those work.

This is a rails 2 project.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Did you namespace the helper file as well? This should work:

`app/helpers/api/ott_helper.rb`

In the file:

`module Api::OttHelper`

Comment: Weird. I have a Rails 2 app with namespacing and can confirm that it does work. So if you arrange things like: `app/controllers/api/ott_controller.rb`, `app/views/api/ott/playlists.html.erb` and `app/helpers/api/ott_helper.rb` the playlists view is unable to access the helper methods?